# It is okay to migrate to Asp.NET 4.0 now?

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0

Okay today, as most of you noticed Framework 4.0 has been released. I've been working on a project which is being built on framework 3.5. Since I want to use dynamic keyword and most of the asp.net features like Tableless Menu Control, ClientIDMode and clean web.config etc. I am kinda urging to migrate the unfinished project to 4.0 but I am little hesitating about that.Some times I think it is way better to wait for SP1.

So what do you think about it? You guys will migrate to unfinished projects or will still hang out with 3.5 for a while.

Thanks.

Comment: Now?  I migrated half a year ago.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The .Net 4.0 runtime environment has been out for a while (mind you not RTM, but RC1 and so forth).  A lot of people have tested it and I would guess that almost all of the bugs have been shaken out.  There should be no problem switching at this point. They have introduced a number of items that improve .Net.  Are they necessary, no, but they can make programming in .Net easier.

You can always download 4.0 locally and test it out on your project.  Worse comes to worse, the project blows up and you reload it from your source control system.

What you should be aware of is that there are breaking changes in both C# and VB.Net in 4.0 runtime environment.  You'll need to watch out for those.

Answer (score 2):

The following probably applies to most framework-base development.

1. **Do the new features save more time than fixing the old things the upgrade breaks?**

   If you're going to waste lots of time making old things work, perhaps you're better off just to sit it out on 3.x and port to 4.x at a later phase.

   If you really *need* features from 4.0 and would have to spend time implementing them yourself, perhaps it's a net time saving.
2. **Can you support this version of the framework?** (ie can your server people handle the upgrades and monitor things okay?)

   If your server bods can't make this work in the field, give up now. I don't know your organisational structure or who runs your servers but I know some companies have a pretty thorough testing regime they'll put software through before allowing it. As a brand new version, they might be weary.

   And let's be frank, just because something goes through several pre-release versions, they don't catch every bug because they're rarely used in production scenarios. You know the drill.

   And if installing 4.0 on the server breaks old things, you might be waiting a long time.
3. **Is your project's launch likely going to be after the first round of bug fixes?**

   If you're developing this for 3+ months away, you've probably got enough time to sort the platform issues, fix the code issues and get framework bugs reported with the (blind) hope that they fix them or you can work around them safely.

   If you're launching tomorrow, it's not enough time to test it.

Answer (score 1):

I will only upgrade when there is a need to do it.  For example I have one application that must use features delivered in .Net Framework 4.  So that application will get upgraded ASAP.

I have another application that is 3.5 with no driving need to upgrade at this time.  That one will get upgraded when time and budget allows.

Comment: Practical.  Of course, you can still target 3.5, 3.0, and 2.0 in Visual Studio 2010.